# Raspi Vnc connection refused

Tags: raspbian, connection, vnc

I install Raspbian with a NOOB SD card. Then I updated it, following a guide. I installed tightvncserver on the Raspberry Pi and configured it.

Then, with my Windows pc using putty, I connected to the Raspberry Pi.

Using the command: `vncserver :0 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24` causes the message:

> Warning: raspberrypi:0 is taken because of /tmp/.X0-lock
>
> Remove this file if there is no X server
>
> raspberrypi:0
>
> A VNC server is already running as :0

but using the same command replacing 0 with 1 the server seems to work. When I'm going to begin a connection from a Windows PC to the RaspberryPi with a VNC viewer I have the message `connection refused`.

What do I have to do to have a VNC connection with the Raspberry Pi and use it from my Windows PC?

Thank you for helping me! Yes! With putty the connection to raspi works. With putty everything is ok.. But when i try to use vnc it doesn't work and vnc viewer give the message "connect: connection refused(10061)"...

But putty is working and with putty i can use my raspi and i already saw that on raspberry the vnc is started and is working.

Comment: Have you tried just connecting to the Raspberry Pi using putty? This will display a LXTerminal like window on your computer. From there you can start the VNC service. Then input the ip adress of your Pi into VNC Viewer and you should be good to go. Or you could just trying connecting to your Pi using VNC viewer on your computer.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Yes! With putty the connection to raspi works. With putty everything is ok.. But when i try to use vnc it doesn't work and vnc viewer give the message "connect: connection refused(10061)"... But putty is working and with putty i can use my raspi and i already saw that on raspberry the vnc is started and is working.

Answer (score -1):

I would check what ports each is trying to operate on... sounds like the server's port is different from the client's port.

Comment: A complete answer would explain how to do this.

Comment: ok, so How can I see what is the right port for the VNC connection?